# Store reverse in an integer c++

Tags: c++, integer

I have used reverse code in one of the program, I donot want to actually output the reverse in my program. I want to store that reverse integer so that i can use it somewhere else too. 
This is my code of reversing an integer, please tell me how to store this reverse in seperate integer . Without using character array.

This is my some piece of code

---

```
            int integer;
            int rev;

            do{

                rev=integer%10;
                integer=integer/10;
                cout<<rev;

            }while(integer!=0);
```

Comment: one way is to generate the digits of the integer, using one the standard library's functions for that. then you can reverse the sequence, using the standard library's function for that. and then you can interpret the reversed digit sequence as an integer value specification, producing an integer, by using one of the standard library's functions for that.

Comment: 123 is 3+2×10+1×10×10 or (1×10+2)×10+3. 321 is 1+2×10+3×10×10 or (3×10+2)×10+1. In your code, if `integer` is `123`, `rev` will be successively `3`, then `2`, then `1`. The solution shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: This comment comes probably far too late, but you can wonder what use it is to store this "reversed" integer into an integer. Because if you need the decimal digits, you will have to perform the conversion from binary to decimal anyway, and it makes no real difference to output the digits left to right or right to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet:

```
int integer = 123456789;
int rev = 0;

while (integer!=0) {
    rev = (10 * rev)      // move all digits one to the left: 98  --> 980
        + (integer % 10); // add rightmost digit from input   980 --> 987
    integer /= 10;        // delete rightmost digit           1234567 --> 123456
}

printf("%d", rev);
```

Comment: Its working but please explain me this line rev = (10 * rev) + (integer % 10);  .I am bit confused.

Comment: I think that the questioner made the point with the previous comment. For once a "newbie question" is _not_ explicitly asking "please give me code", someone posts a full code without explanation...

Comment: Thanks everyone I understood the logic